# IntelliJ IDEA: Why is readLine() expecting two user inputs instead of one using Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

I wrote a simple program that takes the user's input from the console and then prints it. But when the user enters the input, it requests a second user input and only reads the second input.

Code:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    print("Enter text: ")
    val stringInput = readLine()!!
    println("Readed text: $stringInput")
}
```

Console:

```
> Task :MainKt.main()
Enter text: FirstInput
SecondInput
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:37282', transport: 'socket'
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:37264', transport: 'socket'
Readed text: SecondInput
```

I'm using the latest version of IntelliJ IDEA. I don't know why this is happening. I'm using Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in IntelliJ's internal console: see [this ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-673) (found via [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65184427/10134209)).

(The same issue also appears to be behind [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65100768/readline-only-reads-second-input-in-console) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65019899/problem-with-kotlin-readline-function-using-intellij-internal-console).)

I don't know if it refers to the same problem, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65001965/10134209) recommends changing the JRE options in the Edit Configurations menu, and then changing them back again.

Comment: After changing the JRE Options it works as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

It might be because you are using "!!". Double bang (!!) or double exclamation operator or not-null assertion operator is used with variables that you are sure the value will be always be asserted (not null). If a value is null and one uses "!!", a one null pointer exception will be thrown. So, this operator is only used if we want to throw one exception always if any null value is found.

In your case:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    print("Enter text: ")

    val stringInput = readLine()
    println("Readed text: $stringInput")
}
```

You would want to use !! for example:

```
fun main(args: Array) {
   println("Enter text: ")
   val stringInput = null

   val inputLength = stringInput!!.length

   println("Length of the string is : $inputLength")

}
```

Since user input is null, the length of string would be null, hence The program will throw one kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException

Comment: Please explain why `!!` is problematic

Comment: The problem persist even without the `!!`

Comment: @Lizzie I can think of the following possibilities at the moment:
  - Did you mistakenly declare 2 public static void main method?
  - Check if you have clicked on "Mute Breakpoints" button 
  - Try maven clean followed by maven install

Comment: @Lizzie  Click on debug again and in the right-hand corner, you should see a tool bar. There's an icon that looks like two red break points overlapping. Click on that. It will pop open a menu under any exception. Please ensure that Enabled, Suspend, All, Condition, log message to console and log evaluated expression are all checked.