# Why IntelliJIDEA Kotlin doesn't take input from readLine() when running the main file in Console Application?

Tags: kotlin

[image]

Taking input as commandline works fine though!

It seems i need to enter twice to get an input. Cant seem to understand why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IntelliJ IDEA: Why is readLine() expecting two user inputs instead of one using Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65281189/intellij-idea-why-is-readline-expecting-two-user-inputs-instead-of-one-using)

Comment: @gidds Nope. It didnt work. I did feel though it was a bug!

Answer (score 0):

the best answer I came up With is it's bug in IntelliJ's internal console: same thing happened with be and when I run it in older version it works fine