# readLine() function not working in Intellij Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, input

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {

   var str = readLine()
    var result = str?.reversed()
    print(result)

}
```

I am also attaching my console image so that you can see nothing happens. It seems readLine() function not working. Help required to understand the reason.[image]

Comment: Have you given it a line to read? It hasn't printed ``null`` yet

Comment: Yep, when I wrote " abhas " once again in nextline. It worked. Thanks. But why it hasn't worked for first line of console?

Comment: Your code works fine for me, I run it, type a line and then it reverses it. It should handle the first line you type after you call ``readLine()`` - it doesn't read anything that was previously typed into the console, if that's what you were looking for?

Comment: Known issue with IntelliJ's internal console. See here for more examples, a link to the ticket and a possible solution. [IntelliJ IDEA: Why is readLine() expecting two user inputs instead of one using Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65281189/intellij-idea-why-is-readline-expecting-two-user-inputs-instead-of-one-using). This question is a duplicate.